# How to add wrapper in checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, template, css, design

I want to add **container div** and add **Shipping address** and **Order summary** in it as below design.
How can i do that?

[image: Checkout]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order summary comes from 
module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html at checkout page.

You just need to change wrapper class here:

```
Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
        'type': 'custom',
        'modalClass': 'opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper',
        'wrapperClass': 'checkout-container',
        'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
        'responsive': true,
        'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
        'overlayClass': 'modal-custom-overlay',
        'buttons': []
    }}">
```

to

```
Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
        'type': 'custom',
        'modalClass': 'opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper',
        'wrapperClass': 'custome-wrapper',
        'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
        'responsive': true,
        'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
        'overlayClass': 'modal-custom-overlay',
        'buttons': []
    }}">
```

Add wrapper `div` at `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html`

```
<div class="custome-wrapper">
    <div class="opc-wrapper">
        <ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
       </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```